# Hashmap and hashtable in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, hashtable, hashmap

I am really confused on how these 2 collections behave in multithreaded environment.

Hash table is synchronized that means no 2 threads will be updating its value simultaneously right?

Answer (score 14):

Look at [ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)s for Thread safe Maps.

They offer all the features of HashTable with a performance very close to a HashMap.

Performance is gained by instead of using a map wide lock, the collection maintains a list of 16 locks by default, each of which is used to lock a single bucket of the map. You can even configure the number of buckets :) Tweaking this can help performance depending on your data.

I can't recommend enough Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz
http://jcip.net/

I still learn something new every time I read it.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly,  HashTable is synchronized that mean that it's safe to use it in multi-thread environment (many thread access the same HashTable) If two thread try to update the hashtable at the sametime, one of them will have to wait that the other thread finish his update.

HashMap is not synchronized, so it's faster, but you can have problem in a multi-thread environment.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that Hashtable and `Collections.synchronizedMap` are safe only for individual operations. Any operations involving multiple keys or check-then-act that need to be atomic will *not* be so and additional client side locking will be required.

For example, you cannot write any of the following methods without additional locking:

- swap the values at two different keys: `swapValues(Map, Object k1, Object k2)`
- append the parameter to value at a key: `appendToValue(Map, Object k1, String suffix)`

And yes, all of this is covered in JCIP :-)

Comment: `ConcurrentMap` adds a few very useful methods to `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the methods are done atomically, but values() method not (see [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#values())).

Paul was faster than me recommending you the java.util.concurrent package, which gives you a very fine control and data structures for multithreade environments.

Comment: Problem will arise only if we have instance variables right ?
With the variables that are declared and used inside method signature will not have issues in multithreaded environment. Please correct if wrong.

Comment: Problems may arise *faster* with instance variables, but that's not the problem. The problem is sharing variables without any type of *control*. I use a static ConcurrentHashMap without problems (I absolutely agree with Paul's answer) :)

Comment: The parameter of a method call or a constructor may not be an instance (nor class) variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables are synchronized but they're an old implementation that you could almost say is deprecated.  Also, they don't allow null keys (maybe not null values either? not sure).

One problem is that although every method call is synchronized, most interesting actions require more than one call so you have to synchronize around the several calls.

A similar level of synchronization can be obtained for HashMaps by calling:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
```

which wraps a map in synchronized method calls.  But this has the same concurrency drawbacks as Hashtable.

As Paul says, ConcurrentHashMaps provide thread safe maps with additional useful methods for atomic updates.

Comment: Hashtables aren't yet deprecated (not sure why), but the Dictionary Interface they implement is considered obsolete.