# Why should we use HashMap in multi-threaded environments?

Tags: java, hashmap, synchronized

Today I was reading about how HashMap works in Java. I came across a blog and I am quoting directly from the article of the blog. I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361784/hashmap-and-hashtable-in-multithreaded-environment) article on Stack Overflow. Still
I want to know the detail.

> So the answer is Yes there is potential race condition exists while
> resizing HashMap in Java, if two thread at the same time found that
> now HashMap needs resizing and they both try to resizing. on the
> process of resizing of HashMap in Java , the element in bucket which
> is stored in linked list get reversed in order during there migration
> to new bucket because java HashMap  doesn't append the new element at
> tail instead it append new element at head to avoid tail traversing.
> If race condition happens then you will end up with an infinite loop.

It states that as HashMap is not thread-safe during resizing of the HashMap a potential race condition can occur. I have seen in our office projects even, people are extensively using HashMaps knowing they are not thread safe. If it is not thread safe, why should we use HashMap then? Is it just lack of knowledge among developers as they might not be aware about structures like ConcurrentHashMap or some other reason. Can anyone put a light on this puzzle.

Comment: Making structures thread-safe needs additional runtime work (CPU cycles). So if thread-safety isn't an issue, `HashMap` is more efficient

Comment: It is not a good choice if it is shared, but if it is restricted to a single thread there is no issue... There are use cases for both situations...

Comment: If you can ensure single-threaded access to that `HashMap`, you can use it safely. Otherwise, start and ask yourself questions...

Answer (score 8):

I can confidently say ConcurrentHashMap is a pretty ignored class. Not many people know about it and not many people care to use it. The class offers a very robust and fast method of synchronizing a Map collection. I have read a few comparisons of HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap on the web. Let me just say that they’re totally wrong. There is no way you can compare the two, one offers synchronized methods to access a map while the other offers no synchronization whatsoever.

What most of us fail to notice is that while our applications, web applications especially, work fine during the development & testing phase, they usually go tilts up under heavy (or even moderately heavy) load. This is due to the fact that we expect our HashMap’s to behave a certain way but under load they usually misbehave. Hashtable’s offer concurrent access to their entries, with a small caveat, the entire map is locked to perform any sort of operation.

While this overhead is ignorable in a web application under normal load, under heavy load it can lead to delayed response times and overtaxing of your server for no good reason. This is where ConcurrentHashMap’s step in. They offer all the features of Hashtable with a performance almost as good as a HashMap. ConcurrentHashMap’s accomplish this by a very simple mechanism.

Instead of a map wide lock, the collection maintains a list of 16 locks by default, each of which is used to guard (or lock on) a single bucket of the map. This effectively means that 16 threads can modify the collection at a single time (as long as they’re all working on different buckets). Infact there is no operation performed by this collection that locks the entire map.

Comment: The locks in ConcurrentHashMap are not at the bucket level. They're at partition level. And each partition contains several buckets.

Answer (score 2):

There are several aspects to this: First of all, most of the collections are not thread safe. If you want a thread safe collection you can call [`synchronizedCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29) or [`synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29)

But the main point is this: You want your threads to run in parallel, no synchronization at all - if possible of course. This is something you should strive for but of course cannot be achieved every time you deal with multithreading. 
But there is no point in making the default collection/map thread safe, because it should be an edge case that a map is shared. Synchronization means more work for the jvm.

Comment: You can't always have your threads run independently from one another, resource sharing is not an edge case. What good would a thread be if it didn't share anything? That's the edge case. Consider most scientific problems that break a problem into sub-problems, or a listener thread that waits for input (and then offloads it to a processor thread).

Comment: Of course you have to share data from time to time but you should try to not to do that, because every time you synchronize you loose the benefit of having multiple threads. Thas what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

In a multithreaded environment, you have to ensure that it is not modified concurrently or you can reach a critical memory problem, because it is not synchronized in any way.

Dear just check Api previously I also thinking in same manner.

I thought that the solution was to use the static Collections.synchronizedMap method. I was expecting it to return a better implementation. But if you look at the source code you will realize that all they do in there is just a wrapper with a synchronized call on a mutex, which happens to be the same map, not allowing reads to occur concurrently.

In the Jakarta commons project, there is an implementation that is called FastHashMap. This implementation has a property called fast. If fast is true, then the reads are non-synchronized, and the writes will perform the following steps:

```
Clone the current structure
Perform the modification on the clone
Replace the existing structure with the modified clone 
public class FastSynchronizedMap implements Map,   
Serializable {

private final Map m;
private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

.
.
.

public V get(Object key) {
lock.readLock().lock();
V value = null;
try {
    value = m.get(key);
} finally {
    lock.readLock().unlock();
}
return value;
}

public V put(K key, V value) {
lock.writeLock().lock();
V v = null;
try {
    v = m.put(key, value);
} finally {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
}
return v;
}

.
.
.
}
```

Note that we do a try finally block, we want to guarantee that the lock is released no matter what problem is encountered in the block.

This implementation works well when you have almost no write operations, and mostly read operations.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap can be used when a single thread has an access to it. However when multiple threads start accessing the Hashmap there will be 2 main problems:
1. resizing of hashmap is not gauranteed to work as expected.
2. Concurrent Modification exception would be thrown. This can also be thrown when its accessed by single thread to read and write onto the hashmap at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for using HashMap in multi-threaded environment is to initialize it with the expected number of objects' count, hence avoiding the need for a re-sizing.