# Get and Put to Map at same time in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency

I have one doubt. What will happen if I get from map at same time when I am putting to map some data?

What I mean is if `map.get()` and `map.put()` are called by two separate processes at the same time. Will `get()` wait until `put()` has been executed?

Comment: See this link might me this is useful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688629/is-a-hashmap-thread-safe-for-different-keys

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361784/hashmap-and-hashtable-in-multithreaded-environment

Answer (score 5):

It depends on which Map implementation you are using.

For example, `ConcurrentHashMap` supports full concurrency, and `get()` will not wait for `put()` to get executed, and stated in the Javadoc :

```
 * <p> Retrieval operations (including <tt>get</tt>) generally do not
 * block, so may overlap with update operations (including
 * <tt>put</tt> and <tt>remove</tt>). Retrievals reflect the results
 * of the most recently <em>completed</em> update operations holding
 * upon their onset.
```

Other implementations (such as `HashMap`) don't support concurrency and shouldn't be used by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: "shouldn't be used by multiple threads at the same time" ... without additional synchronization.

Comment: @DanAllen That's true, but since there are standard implementations that already support concurrency, there's less motivation to use the basic classes and add custom synchronization.

Comment: I agree except when the map is part of the internal state of some greater object that itself has synchronization round it. Maps are very common both as inside objects and as exposed points of concurrent interaction.

Answer (score 2):

It might throw ConcurrentModificationException- not sure about it. It is always better to use synchronizedMap.This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap method.This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the map:

```
Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an interface, so the answer depends on the implementation you're using.

Generally speaking, the simpler implementations of this interface, such as [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) are **not thread safe**. If you don't have some synchronization built around them, concurrently `put`ing and `get`ing will result in an undefined behavior - you may get the new value, you may get the old one, bust most probably you'd just get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, or something worse.

If you want to handle the same `Map` from different threads, either use one of the implementations of a [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) (e.g., a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)), which guarantees a happens-before-sequence (i.e., if the `get` was fired before the `put`, you'd get the old value, even if the `put` is ongoing, and vise-versa), or synchronize the `Map`'s access (e.g., by calling [`Collections#synchronizedMap(Map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-).